# laravel catch image in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my html code

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'admins.changePicture', 'class' => 'mainInformationContrainer', 'method'=> 'POST', 'file' => true)) }}
<ul>
    <li>
        <label>Picture</label>
        <div class="oneInfo thumbnail">
            <img src="#" id="imageID">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>.</label>
        <div class="oneInfo" style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden">
            <span class="spanForFileInput">

                <input type="button" class="selectImage" value="Select Image" />
                <input type="file" value="Select Image" id="imgInp"/>
            </span>
            <input type="submit"  />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label></label>
        <div class="oneInfo">

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

and in my controller I do this

```
public function changePicture(){
    $image = Input::file('imageID');echo $image; exit;
}
```

I got an empty result

my question is how to catch the image in the controller and if you how to save it to my sql database? my column is from type `longblob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an empty result because you have this:

```
<input type="file" value="Select Image" id="imgInp"/>
```

There is no name but only an `id` so you need to add a `name` in your input like this:

```
<input type="file" value="Select Image" id="imgInp" name="imgInp" />
```

Now you may use this:

```
$image = Input::file('imgInp');
```

Save the data in the database:

```
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents(Input::file('imgInp')->getRealPath()));
```

Now insert the `$image` in your database field and to show it in your view just use:

```
// Assumed the field in the database is imageField
$imgdata = base64_decode($model->imageField);
$f = finfo_open();
$ext = finfo_buffer($f, $model->imageField, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo '<img src="data:image/' . $ext . ';base64,' . $model->imageField . '" />';
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Hope you good today. 
could you check my question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465200/laravel-how-to-update-a-field-to-a-database

Comment: Hello, could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843547/laravel-set-disabled-select-option appreciate the efforts