# laravel how to update a field to a database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This is my code

```
$admin = Admin::find(25);
        $admin->picture = $destination;
        $admin->save();
```

but when I execute it, the `picture` field is keep `NULL` for example `images/admin_20`

the `destination` is a string to the location of the image.

I already tried `->update()` but also nothing becomes saved.

could you help me please

#### Edit 1

the `picture` column in my database is `varchar(255)    utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: I think you should check your `$destination` data to make sure it has content .. try `var_dump($destination)` cause from what i see, i think the data is not set

Comment: @zaherg I tried var_dump and I got this result : `string(64) "C:\xampp2\htdocs\ParkingProject\public/adminsImages/admin_20.jpg"`

Comment: try this, try to define a value to the `$destination` like : `$destination='what';` then execute your code, and see if it will save the new value or not, plus which Laravel you use ?

Comment: @zaherg still `NULL` , I am using laravel 4.2

Comment: help guys ...........

Comment: so strange, I suspect that the issue with the special char, but since you said you have change it to a default value and the value of the picture stays `Null`, so this drop the special char issue .. if you tried to create a new admin does everything work ?

Comment: @zaherg when I create the admin I don't allow him/her to add image, but then later, when he sign in, I make the change image interface available, plus, the picture column wasn't in the admin table but then (three days ago) I added it, does that matter? i don't think so right?

Comment: you can just try to create a new admin manually via the code and add a value to the images, this is just to debug the code, not about the logic, plus i dont think adding the image field later cause any issue

Comment: @zaherg I just created an admin from the code and I set the picture to `adsfasdf` and when I check my database, I found the new admin and the picture column has the value `adsfasdf`

Comment: is it only the picture field which has this issue or even the other fields ?

Comment: @zaherg I haven't tried to edit the other fields yet. I will try and update you

Comment: @zaherg all the fields :(

Comment: am not sure, you need to check `fillable` and `guarded` maybe you have used them in the wrong way in your `Admin` class

Comment: @zaherg I don't have any `fillable`, I just have `protected $guarded = array('ID');` does that matter?

Comment: I dont think this is the issue, but i think the `id` should be small letter not capital.

Comment: @zaherg in my database the id is `ID` and it is working with me.

Comment: then am speechless about this :( sorry ..

Comment: @zaherg many thanks for the efforts

Comment: @zaherg I found the problem, check my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, three days working to this silly mistake

the `ID` column in my database should have been `id`

Comment: nice .. I told you i smell something fishy about the `ID` ;)

Comment: @zaherg could you check my new question please ?

Comment: not sure which question, can you post the link for it ? or send it to my twitter @zaherg

Comment: @zaherg this is the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500198/laravel-which-route-or-link-should-i-use-for-this-case I have asked you for another question but I will try to solve it later, now this is the new problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     $admin = Admin::where('id', '=', 25);
     $admin->picture = $destination;
     $admin->save();
```

You didn't provide much code but if it's a function

```
      Return $admin->picture;
```

**EDIT**

Laravel is UTF8 by default but just to make sure, check the file

```
 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
 collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
 init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
 character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: the `$admin` is already working, there is no wrong in getting the admin variable, I am using it and I can call data from it like this $admin->name and I got the correct result. I am thinking that maybe because the `destination` variable has special characters? I printed it in the comments please check

Comment: where is the `etc/mysql` ? I couldn't find it